# Show that $f: S \to S^*$ is continuous iff for every sequences $s_n \to s$ in $S$, >we have $f(s_n) \to f(s)$ in S*

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove this.

> Let $(S, d)$ and $(S^*, d^*)$ be metric space.
> Show that
> $f:S \to S^*$ is continuous iff for every sequences $s_n \to s$ in $S$,
> we have $f(s_n) \to f(s)$ in S*

But I have a definition that
$x_0 \in E$, $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for all $x_n \in E$, $x_n \to x_0$ we have $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$

Aren't these the same statements? Aren't the proofs for both statements the same?

Comment: What is $S^{*}$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh sorry. f: S -> S*. I'll fix it

Comment: I assume you meant "$f(s_n)\to f(s)$" in your highlighted statement. Yes, these two statements are the same.

Comment: @freakish oh you are right. That's a typo. Thanks!

Comment: It's common to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to prove the sequence definition for continuity. Is the problem asking for that proof coming from the same textbook (or other resource) that provides that definition you posted?